# Forcing IConfigurationBuilder.Bind() to throw an error when it fails to Bind an object

Tags: c#, config

I have a console app where I'm trying to bind a config section into a list of a custom object type as such:

```
List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>();
config.GetSection("Objects").Bind(myObjectList);
```

```
public enum CustomEnum{
     One,
     Two
}

public class myObject{
    public CustomEnum myEnum { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that if in the config file, you don't give a proper enum value for that property (ie Three instead of One or Two as shown above), it will fail to bind the object, and wont throw an error telling you that it failed. So basically how can I make it so I know a bind failed because of an improper config value? Right now it just doesn't bind those specific ones that fail, meaning there's no real way to know there are items missing.

Example config that successfully binds one object but fails and ignores the other:

```
{
   "Objects": [
      {
         "myEnum": "One"
      },
      {
         "myEnum": "Three"
      }
   ]
}
```

EDIT: So for future reference for anyone finding this, there basically is no good solution. You just need a manual check, or to not use enums at all in your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate the object "By Hand" before binding the object.

Loop through the values of the config as string first. See if they match an existing item in the enum. Using the IsDefined function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.8

If not throw an exception.

If all items are in the enum use the Bind method as usual.

```cs
    public static bool ValidateConfig(object jsonConfig)
    {
         foreach (string item in jsonConfig) // loop through the config items as string
         {
             if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CustomItem), item))
             {
                  throw new Exception("Enum value does not exist.");
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Is there really no better way to do this than manually? Seems to negate the efficiency in using .Bind() in the first place.

Comment: I feel you. But i think at some point you do have to validate somehow anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [post](https://andrewlock.net/adding-validation-to-strongly-typed-configuration-objects-in-asp-net-core/):

> The ASP.NET Core configuration system is very flexible and allows you
>   to use strongly typed settings. However, partly due to this
>   flexibility, it's possible to have configuration errors that only
>   appear in certain environments. By default, these errors will only be
>   discovered when your code attempts to use an invalid configuration
>   value (if at all).
>
> You could use an `IStartupFilter` to validate your settings when your
>   app starts up. This ensures you learn about configuration errors as
>   soon as possible, instead of at run-time.

So at first you need to create an `interface` like this:

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    void Validate();
}
```

And then:

```
public class SettingValidationStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    readonly IEnumerable<IValidatable> _validatableObjects;
    public SettingValidationStartupFilter(IEnumerable<IValidatable> validatableObjects)
    {
        _validatableObjects = validatableObjects;
    }

    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        foreach (var validatableObject in _validatableObjects)
        {
            validatableObject.Validate();
        }

        //don't alter the configuration
        return next;
    }
}
```

Then you need to register the filter with the DI container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{
    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, SettingValidationStartupFilter>()
    // other service configuration
}
```

And finally, you need to implement the `IValidatable` interface on your settings that you want to validate at startup:

```
public class myObject : IValidatable
{
    public CustomEnum myEnum { get; set; }

    public void Validate()
    {
        //Do your validation here
        Validator.ValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), validateAllProperties: true);
    }
}
```

> Whichever approach you use, the Validate() method throws an exception if there is a problem with your configuration and binding.

Comment: Thank you for the article ref, its definitely helpful, although i wish the part where he said it throws an error were actually true :( But based on this though I'd still have to change the property to be of type string in order to get the Bind to work initially, and then check if that string matches the enum right? And then id have to convert it to the enum whenever I want to use it in code